# OpenSimplexNoise values are different in C# and C

Tags: c#, c, noise

In order to use OpenSimplexNoise server-side and client-side (of course I expected the same values), I cloned these 2 repos:

- https://github.com/smcameron/open-simplex-noise-in-c
- https://gist.github.com/digitalshadow/134a3a02b67cecd72181

I ran some tests to check if it is the case and the values are different. I even generated images to check if it wasn't just a "zoom" problem but they have nothing in common!

- Is it normal?
- How can I overcome this?

Edit :
Here is the repo with all the code runnable :
https://github.com/Hell-Martin/Open-Simplex-Noise-C-CS

Comment: You should show the inputs you used, and the code you used to generate the outputs. But this is going to be a tricky problem for anyone to resolve — it requires a lot of effort for anyone to be able to see what you see.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](htps://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name. Here, you need your minimal C# code _and_ your minimal C code. You must explain how to compare the result, too.

Comment: In your C code, you have `struct osn_context *ctx; open_simplex_noise(0,ctx);` but you probably need `struct osn_context ctx; open_simplex_noise(0, &ctx);`.  As it stands, you're passing an uninitialized pointer to a function that cannot change the value in `main()`.  Passing the pointer allowed the function to set the value in `main()`.  You should also be checking the return value from `open_simplex_noise()` — it is probably reporting an error (though it isn't guaranteed; undefined behaviour can sometimes seem to work). It is, however, scribbling at an indeterminate location in memory — BAD!

Comment: You'd need to change the final call to `open_simplex_noise_free(&ctx);` too, assuming that it expects an `osn_context` pointer.  If there were any compilation warnings from the C code, you should have fixed those before posting the code, so I'm assuming the code compiled cleanly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for the reply but all programs are running as expected, the signature is `int open_simplex_noise(int64_t seed, struct osn_context **ctx);`.
I use it as explained by the readme.

The isse is that both programs are showing different values... For same seed !

Comment: I disagree.  You pass an `osn_context *` where the function requires an `osn_context **`.  You need the `&` I showed, though the types I guessed were wrong.  And you won't need to modify the call to the free function.

Comment: Oh yes, the first is wrong cause I copy pasted it from my code and I have a wrapping function like so :
`int init_terrain(int64_t seed, struct osn_context **ctx)
{

    open_simplex_noise(seed,ctx);

}`

Wich I do call like that `int k = init_terrain(1,&ctx);`
My bad you were right on this one :D

Comment: It's impossible to debug approximations to the MCVE code!  It is crucial that you provide exact code that reproduces the problem!

Comment: Done, there is a link to the repository.